# Is 'god' and 'god name' indifferent according to Padma Purana?

Tags: krishna, padma-purana, nama

Nama Japa is a unique feature of sanathan dharma. Continuous recitation of a god's name is called Nama Japa. god's name has divine origin and the scriptures have several statements saying that god name is indifferent from the god herself. I am in search of those references.

consider the following statements by chaitantya mahaprabhu

> “**There is no difference between Kṛṣṇa’s body and Himself or between
> His name and Himself.** But as far as the conditioned soul is concerned,
> one’s name is different from one’s body, from one’s original form and
> so on. ‘The holy name of Kṛṣṇa is transcendentally blissful. It
> bestows all spiritual benedictions, **for it is Kṛṣṇa Himself**, the
> reservoir of all pleasure. Kṛṣṇa’s name is complete, and it is the
> form of all transcendental mellows. It is not a material name under
> any condition, and it is no less powerful than Kṛṣṇa Himself. Since
> Kṛṣṇa’s name is not contaminated by the material qualities, there is
> no question of its being involved with māyā. Kṛṣṇa’s name is always
> liberated and spiritual; it is never conditioned by the laws of
> material nature. **This is because the name of Kṛṣṇa and Kṛṣṇa Himself
> are identical.**’
>
> [132-133, 17: The Lord Travels to Vṛndāvana,  Madhya-līlā, Śrī
> Caitanya-caritāmṛta](https://vedabase.io/en/library/cc/madhya/17/)

the purport of one of these verses refers to Padma Purana. which chapter of Padma Purana mentions this fact?